# How to change the edge loop direction?

Tags: workflow, edges, topology

No, i don't mean rotating the faces. I can't understand exactly how could i change the direction of the edge loop flow! And the problem is theoretical - i need to keep quads and i need to change the edge loop direction exactly like on this video

https://youtu.be/H8K5CyQB_kc

What is happening there looks like magic.

Where can i read about the backstage of this proccess? Because when i try to do something like that manually, i stand two problems:
1. if i'm using to merge vertices it can produce me only 8-vertices sphere.
2. If i'm using knife, i always produce triangles and quads.

HOW DO THEY DO THAT

Comment: in the yt video text description there is a link to an executable with source code, maybe you can get some hint there or here http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2015/MTPPSPC15/

Comment: i donwloaded and plaed with an executable but still i can't catch the algorhythm